# How to extract complete URL without HTTP in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, url

I want to extract the complete URL except HTTP. I have used [Domain](https://www.npmjs.org/package/domain) and [url](https://www.npmjs.org/package/url).

Here is my code

```
var url = require('url');
var domain=require('domain.js');

var url_parts = 'http://static01.nyt.com/images/2014/11/17/business/billboardjump/billboardjump-master675.jpg'; 

var website=domain(url.parse(url_parts));
var querystring = (url.parse(url_parts, true)).path;

console.log(website+querystring);
```

But only I am getting

```
'nyt.com/images/2014/11/17/business/billboardjump/billboardjump-master675.jpg'
```

instead of

```
'static01.nyt.com/images/2014/11/17/business/billboardjump/billboardjump-master675.jpg'
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just calculate protocol length and drop it:

```
var u = 'http://static01.nyt.com/images/2014/11/17/business/billboardjump/billboardjump-master675.jpg';
var protocol = url.parse(u).protocol;
console.log(u.slice((protocol + '//').length));
```

Comment: Why use an URL parser if you do string slicing in the end?

Comment: because it's already available and you don't need to parse protocol part yourself

Answer (score 0):

```
const urlString = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26987567/how-to-extract-complete-url-without-http-in-node-js"

const [protocol, urlWithoutProtocol] = urlString.split('://');

console.log(protocol, urlWithoutProtocol)
```

Comment: cool way too, but it doesn't account for urls without protocols

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!Str.match(/^(http|https)/i))
  Str = "https://" + str;
```

if the `Str` doesn't have a `^` at beginning, add it.